# Drupal WSOD on admin pages only, whenever any non-core module is enabled

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, wsod

I have a new installation of drupal 6.22 and one of the first things I did was to install CCK. Enabling this module gave me a WSOD on the whole site, so I deleted the module directory from sites/all/modules. This got rid of the WSOD but now whenever I enable a non-core module, the front-end of the site continues to work but the admin screen give me a wsod. I have read the drupal docs on this and installed dtools. With dtools on, I can see I'm getting the error

```
ERROR: Callback: system_main_admin_page() doesn't exist!
```

I am guessing that deleting the CCK files without disabling the module (CCK) may be part of the problem. How do I programmatically disable modules? Any other ideas on fixing this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have basically a fresh install, it wouldn't be difficult to just reinstall Drupal which should solve your problem.  If you don't wish to do that, you can disable modules in the database through phpMyAdmin, a DB query etc.

If in phpMyAdmin, go to the `system` table, find the module(s) you want to disable and change the status from `1` to `0`.

Comment: Thanks, the reinstall is necessary because disabling the modules hasn't helped. Not a particularly nice first experience with drupal so far! Installing a module that is very widely used and part of core in the next version totally broke my site in a way that is very hard to debug -- anyone heard of exception handling?